# custom empty() function

Tags: php, function, isset

Today I've created a function called `is_empty()`. The function is similar to already existing `empty()` function - it adds a few more checks that are required by my script.

However, now when I run the script and some value is not set, I get the: `Notice: Undefined index` notice. The default `empty()` function display this notice and it assumes the value is empty, is there some way to configure my function to do the same? Instead of using `isset()` together with `is_empty()`?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: My function is here:

```
function is_empty($value, $integer = FALSE){
    if($integer){
        return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
    }
    return empty($value);
}
```

Comment: ... without your function code, this isn't much that can be done

Comment: `empty()` is not a function, you cannot implement something that behaves like it.

Comment: Post your code. And i'm wondering what kind of checks you function does that are not covered by empty?

Comment: `$return` isn't used by your code. The regex line is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notice does not come from some checks you do inside your function. The notice comes from passing some argument to your function, i.e. before the function body is actually executed. Therefore, you cannot change this by implementing the function in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this:

```
  function is_empty($value, $integer = FALSE){
    if (!empty($value)){
    if($integer !== FALSE){
        $return = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $value);
        return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
    }
    return empty($value);
    }
    return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: `empty()` calls make no sense in your code. You may remove them and **nothing** would change. so `if (!empty($value)){` -> `if (!$value){` etc

Comment: @zerkms `empty` will suppress the Undefined var notice.

Comment: As soon as it's passed as a function argument - it's **ALWAYS** defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of is_empty function

```
function is_empty(&$var)
{
    return is_string($var) ? trim( $var ) == '' : empty($var);
}
```

The solution is to pass variable by reference.

Here is another sample like this:

[custom function that uses isset() returning undefined variables when used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344821/custom-function-that-uses-isset-returning-undefined-variables-when-used)

Hope this will help.