# custom function that uses isset() returning undefined variables when used

Tags: php, variables, undefined, isset

I have a field that depends has custom text if a certain condition is met...and if it isn't the field is blank.

I have written a custom function test if a variable is set

```
function AmISet($fieldName) {

if (isset($fieldName)) {

    echo "I am set";
}else{
    echo "I am not set";    
    }
};
```

but when I attach it the field I get an error that the variable is undefined.  But when I do a regular `isset($fieldName);`
I don't have a problem.  Is there any way to get around this and have my function do this instead of the isset()?

I want to add other logic in the function but I only want it to work if the variable is set...but I don't want the undefined error if it is not.

I am new to php and really appreciate any help or direction you can give me.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: `isset()` is not a function but a language construct. There's no way to write a function that accepts non-existing variables without complaint. Perhaps if you elaborate on where `$fieldName` comes from and why it can be empty we could think of a solution.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the $fieldName comes from a query that is performed when a checkbox is checked.  If the box is checked the query is made and the variable is set from the query, if not it doesn't exist and the field is blank.  So sometimes a user could have field values and other times they wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the variable by reference:

```
function AmISet(&$fieldName) {
    if (isset($fieldName)) {
        echo "I am set\n";
    } else {
        echo "I am not set\n";    
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
$fieldName = 'foo';
AmISet($fieldName); // I am set

unset($fieldName);
AmISet($fieldName); // I am not set
```

However, this function is not useful as it is, because it will only output a string. You can create a function that accepts a variable and return if it exists (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836515/what-is-the-php-shorthand-for-print-var-if-var-exist)):

```
function issetor(&$var, $default = false) {
    return isset($var) ? $var : $default;
}
```

Now it can be used like so:

```
echo issetor($fieldName); // If $fieldName exists, it will be printed
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, this is what I have been looking for!

Comment: @DanFromGermany What you mean of "accept the first answer", here I don't think it is right to say to any user like this to accept your answer when OP accept the answer of another user.

Comment: *What am I gonna do 2moz? Copy some answers right after they got posted, change a little bit and hopefully earn the rep! That gonna be  hella fun!*

Comment: issetor() function doesn't work on nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

> the `$fieldName` comes from a query that is performed when a checkbox
>   is checked. If the box is checked the query is made and the variable
>   is set from the query, if not it doesn't exist and the field is blank.

[Filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) are designed for this kind of tasks:

```html
<input type="foo" value="1">
```

```php
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo')==='1';
```

(There's also a specific `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` filter you can pass as second argument.)

And now you have a pure PHP boolean that always exists.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This looks very promising.  I will have to rewrite my page now to include this and then I don't have to deal with the undefined variable problem.